# tortoise svn commit message template:ignore text after this line

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I'm using the *tsvn:logtemplate* property to provide a commit message template. Is there a way to mark lines as to be ignored (not part of the commit message)? When I commit via the command line and `vi`, the message is already filled in with

```
--This line, and those below, will be ignored--

M    foobar.c
A    foobar.h
```

I've tried to use the same line in *tsvn:logtemplate*, but it got committed as-is. Did I miss something in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is not (yet) implemented.